# Does TFS have a source control view similar to the Mainframe Endeavor product

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

How can I see what code is currently sitting in each environment in TFS? On the mainframe I can use a product called Endeavor that will allow me to see all of the environments and what version if any of a program currently resides in that environment.

for example,

```
Test                                                 
PgmA (with additional changes to the Prod version)      

Integration


User

Pre-Prod

Prod
PgmA (current production version of program)
```

Would this be set up in different branches within TFS for the different environments ? Or would the builds tell me this ? I can't seem to find an easy method to accomplish this.

Comment: What version control type you use in TFS, Git or TFVC? In TFS source control, there's no concept called **environment**, does the environment means team project or a workspace/repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFS web page, under **Code** tab, you could see all files/items of your team project listed in a Tree View. You could also see the History of those files. In the History, you could see all changesets, each changesets mean a version.
[image]

You could also see those files/items in **[Source Control Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181370(v=vs.100).aspx)** in Visual Studio.

This document is about TFS changesets:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/find-view-changesets

Answer (score 0):

The Release hub has this capability, assuming you're using it to push builds of your software to your environments.